# lattice point on a circle

Tags: analytic-geometry

consider a circle with center (sqrt[2],1/3) and any arbitrary radius.
how do I prove that there is atmost one lattice point on the circle?

also, does there exist an unique cirle with exactly 2004 lattice points inside it?

Comment: It is not true that every circle with this center has at most $1$ lattice point. And if it was, it would make the second question completely trivial.

Comment: What is "a lattice point"? A point with both its coordinates integer numbers?

Comment: @mercio can you prove your statement about the question being wrong?

Comment: @mercio also how do you proceed, assuming the first statement to be true, to the second staement?

Comment: oh lol i mistook lattice points for rational points. The statement is true, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are two lattice points on a circle.
Then the center of that circle is on the bissecting line between those two points.

Since the equation of that line is rational, if it contains $(\sqrt 2,1/3)$ then it must also contain its rational conjugate $(-\sqrt 2,1/3)$. Which means that the line must be the horizontal line $(L) : y=1/3$.

Now since the two lattice points are symmetric around $(L)$, their $y$ coordinates have to sum to $2/3$, which is impossible since they are integers.

Now, since a circle can only contain one lattice point at a time, as you increase the radius of the circle, the number of points inside the circle can only jump by $1$ at a time. So for any integer $n \ge 0$, there is an nonempty open interval $I$ such that every circle of radius $r \in I$ contains exactly $n$ lattice points.

Comment: how do you assert that "the line  must be a rational line and why does the rational conjugate lie on it"?

Comment: call $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2 \Bbb Z$ the coordinates of the two lattice points and compute the equation of the bissector line. You will see that the equation will have all its coefficients in $\Bbb Q$, that's why it is a "rational object". Next, plug $\sqrt 2$ and $1/3$ in the equation and look at what happens.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question! thanks for the answer.